# How to make VectorAssembler do not compress data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I want  to transform multiple columns to one column using `VectorAssembler`,but the data is compressed by default without other options.

```
val arr2= Array((1,2,0,0,0),(1,2,3,0,0),(1,2,4,5,0),(1,2,2,5,6))
val df=sc.parallelize(arr2).toDF("a","b","c","e","f")
val colNames=Array("a","b","c","e","f")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(colNames)
  .setOutputCol("newCol")
val transDF= assembler.transform(df).select(col("newCol"))
transDF.show(false)
```

The input is:

```
  +---+---+---+---+---+
  |  a|  b|  c|  e|  f|
  +---+---+---+---+---+
  |  1|  2|  0|  0|  0|
  |  1|  2|  3|  0|  0|
  |  1|  2|  4|  5|  0|
  |  1|  2|  2|  5|  6|
  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

The result is:

```
+---------------------+
|newCol               |
+---------------------+
|(5,[0,1],[1.0,2.0])  |
|[1.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,0.0]|
|[1.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,0.0]|
|[1.0,2.0,2.0,5.0,6.0]|
+---------------------+
```

My expect result is:

```
+---------------------+
|newCol               |
+---------------------+
|[1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]|
|[1.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,0.0]|
|[1.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,0.0]|
|[1.0,2.0,2.0,5.0,6.0]|
+---------------------+
```

What should I do to get my expect result?

Comment: It's just another way to represent the data and will not have any effect on further data processing. When a vector has many zeros it more efficient to use a sparse representation, see SparseVector and DenseVector in spark. In other words, you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: I  run transDF.rdd.map { case Row(feat: DenseVector) => Vectors.dense(feat.toArray) } and get a error(scala.MatchError: [(5,[0,1],[1.0,2.0])] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)),so I want to get data with not compressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to coerce all vectors to their dense representation, you can do it using a User Defined Function :

```
val toDense = udf((v: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector) => v.toDense)
transDF.select(toDense($"newCol")).show

+--------------------+
|         UDF(newCol)|
+--------------------+
|[1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,...|
|[1.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,...|
|[1.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,...|
|[1.0,2.0,2.0,5.0,...|
+--------------------+
```