# Spark 3.0.1 MinMaxScaler giving mixed vector types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have run into an issue with the MinMaxScaler using Spark 3.0.1 where the resulting scaled column has a mix of Dense and Sparse vectors. According to the [Apache Spark 3.0.1 MinMaxScaler documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#minmaxscaler), the resulting column should be DenseVectors. I have recently switched from Apache Spark 2.4.0 to 3.0.1 and do not remember seeing this before.

The input DataFrame's schema is:

```
root
 |-- index: long (nullable = false)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

and I am attempting to scale to data with this code:

```
val scaler = new MinMaxScaler()
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setOutputCol("scaledFeatures")
val scalerModel = scaler.fit(converted)
val scaledData: DataFrame = scalerModel.transform(converted)
scaledData.show()
scaledData.printSchema()
```

The resulting output is:

```
|index|label|            features|      scaledFeatures|
+-----+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|    0|    0|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|(880,[7,17,18,19,...|
|    1|    0|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|(880,[7,17,18,19,...|
|    2|    0|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|(880,[7,17,18,19,...|
|    3|    0|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|(880,[7,17,18,19,...|
|    4|    0|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|
|    5|    0|[0.1772,0.0,0.225...|[0.26380824772964...|
|    6|    0|[0.1896,0.0,0.147...|[0.28226887003126...|
|    7|    0|[0.195,0.0,0.2064...|[0.29030817329164...|
|    8|    0|[0.1945,0.0,0.243...|[0.28956379336013...|
|    9|    0|[0.2089,0.0,0.275...|(880,[0,2,4,5,6,7...|
|   10|    0|[0.2582,0.0,0.314...|(880,[0,2,4,5,6,7...|
```

with a schema of

```
root
 |-- index: long (nullable = false)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- scaledFeatures: vector (nullable = true)
```

Is there a bug in the MinMaxScaler, is my code wrong, or is there something about this I am missing? I need the resulting column to be a DenseVector for the next algorithm that will be used on it.

UPDATE:

First, it looks like I can get around this by using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517220/how-to-make-vectorassembler-do-not-compress-data). I had used a similar method before but it apparently didn't work with the newer version of Spark.

However, the original issue remains. Looking at the [MinMaxScaler source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/MinMaxScaler.scala), the transformation function returns

```
Vectors.dense(values).compressed
```

and [according to the DenseVector documentations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseVector.html), `compressed`

*Returns a vector in either dense or sparse format, whichever uses less storage.*

Am I correct in assuming that either the code or the documentation is wrong, and if so, which one is wrong?